# Que regex debo usar para hacer que no importe que hay antes de cierto patron?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, substring

Ya probe la regex \s*¿? y la  \s*  pero no me funciona... Y nunca logra entrar dentro de ese if, que deberia hacer para que pueda entrar?

```py
input_text = kwargs["InputText"]
user_text = kwargs["UserText"]
user_data = kwargs["UserData"]


trad_bool = False

input_text_for_regex = input_text.lower()

print(input_text)


regex = re.compile(r'((tr:)|(traduce lo siguiente:)|(traduce lo siguiente)|(traduce esto:)|(traduce esto)|(translate that:)|(translate that)|(usa tu traductor:)|(usa tu traductor)|(usa el traductor:)|(usa el traductor)|(use the translator:)|(use the translator)|(use translator:)|(use translator)|(use your translator:)|(use your translator)\s+)')

if regex.match(input_text_for_regex): #verificamos si hay concidencia (este es el if)

    #print("debe traducir...")

    trad_bool = True

    try:

        input_text = re.sub(regex, "" ,input_text).strip()


        translator = Translator() #Creo el objeto de la clase Translator()

        src_lang = translator.detect(input_text).lang
        #print(src_lang)

        input_text = translator.translate(text=input_text, src=src_lang, dest="spanish") #Del idioma sea cual sea que detecte lo pasa a español
        input_text = input_text.text
        #print(input_text)
```

En el

```py
regex = re.compile(r'\s*((tr:)|(traduce lo siguiente:)|(traduce lo siguiente)|(traduce esto:)|(traduce esto)|(translate that:)|(translate that)|(usa tu traductor:)|(usa tu traductor)|(usa el traductor:)|(usa el traductor)|(use the translator:)|(use the translator)|(use translator:)|(use translator)|(use your translator:)|(use your translator)\s+)')
```

Pero aun asi sigue sin entrar al if osea que si pongo:

`tr: hello` Ahi SI funciona y SI lo traduce.

`#<@! XXXX>? tr: hello` Ahi NO funciona y NO lo traduce.

`asassads tr: hello` Ahi NO funciona y NO lo traduce.

`tr: hello #<@! XXXX>?`  Ahi SI funciona y SI lo traduce.

Ahora que debo hacer para que siga traduciendo (osea cumpliendo la condicion del if) en los 2 casos en los que NO traduce ?

Comment: Qué es kwargs? Qué contiene ese arreglo?

Comment: Deberías considerar en vez de hacerlo con regex, declarar un arreglo con las posibles opciones, y luego evalúas si la entrada coincide o está incluida con algún elemento del arreglo.

Comment: Prueba de la siguiente manera: `matches = re.search(regex, input_text_for_regex)` y el  `if` lo cambias por:  `if matches:`

Comment: Hay un problema si pones solo /s eso hace que tr: hello tampoco funcione..

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich sos un genio muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo pongo como respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazlo de la  siguiente manera:

```
matches = re.search(regex, input_text_for_regex)
if matches:
```

NOTA: Olvidé explicarle  porqué no te funcionaba. El `re.matches` evalúa el string desde el inicio, por eso, cuando el string empezaba con `tr:`  funcionaba. En cambio, `search` recorre todo el string.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, y por la explicacion